# How to resolve these LibVLC core vout display errors?

Tags: java, android, libvlc, vlcj

I'm using VLCJ in a desktop java application and LibVLC in an android application, both are reporting the same errors when I play video files.

Whenever I call to play an item I get:

core vout display error: Failed to change zoom
core vout display error: Failed to change source AR

At a guess this looks like it's trying and failing to change some core zoom and aspect ratio properties. But the media still displays and plays fine. It's not stopping my applications, it's more that I'm getting frustrated that my outputs are getting clogged with these errors :)

I'm not using any defined media options, I'm just requesting to play media items using whatever options are set by default in VLC, is this the problem?

Google-ing the errors doesn't turn up these errors specifically so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Did you find it out?

Comment: Alas I'm afraid not.. the log spam is less of an issue now we have better internal logging mechanic of our own we can enable / disable / filter for logs from different sources and different severities. The VLC output seems to crop up all the time even when playing videos in the VLC Player application itself so we've resigned it to being 'one of those things' you live with - as everything seems to be working for us & now the logging doesn't cause us any issues.